# Как получить саму цифру пинга после команды os.system('ping...?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ping

```
import os
def ping(address):
    return os.system('ping %s -n 1' % (address,))
```

Нашел вот такой простой способ сделать пинг до сервера, и получаю такой результат [image: https://i.imgur.com/MTpDjQZ.png]

А как мне теперь взять отсюда само значение пинга? Все в интернете просто спрашивают про сам факт ответа от сервера, а значением никто почему-то не интересуется. Глупый вопрос наверное, я недавно только начал, все уже перерыл.

Comment: Нужно разбить строку для вывода нужного значения, логично же

Answer (score 1):

Действия:

- Используйте `subprocess` для считывания результата выполнения `ping`
- Останется распарсить текст, например регулярным выражением с помощью модуля `re`

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/016b05e803b2046f00ad2467ad73ee755845ee4f/subprocess_example/ping.py#L11)

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import re


ping_res = Popen("ping ya.ru", stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

text = ''
for line in ping_res.stdout.readlines():
    text += line.decode('cp866')

print(text)
# Обмен пакетами с ya.ru [87.250.250.242] с 32 байтами данных:
# Ответ от 87.250.250.242: число байт=32 время=26мс TTL=54
# Ответ от 87.250.250.242: число байт=32 время=26мс TTL=54
# Ответ от 87.250.250.242: число байт=32 время=26мс TTL=54
# Ответ от 87.250.250.242: число байт=32 время=26мс TTL=54
#
# Статистика Ping для 87.250.250.242:
#     Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 4, потеряно = 0
#     (0% потерь)
# Приблизительное время приема-передачи в мс:
#     Минимальное = 26мсек, Максимальное = 26 мсек, Среднее = 26 мсек

items = re.findall(r'TTL=(\d+)', text)
print(items)
# ['54', '54', '54', '54']

m = re.search(r'Пакетов: отправлено = (\d+), получено = (\d+), потеряно = (\d+)', text)
if m:
    print(m.groups())
    # ('4', '4', '0')
```

---

**PS.**

**cp866** -- кодировка консоли винды